# Load 20 by 20 items with FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

In this chat app, I'm using `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` and I want to load 20 by 20 message items. On start, I set `keyReg`:

```
  keyRef=mFirebaseDatabaseReference
        .child("messagesKeys")
        .child(usernameFromEmail(mFirebaseUser.getEmail()))
        .child(room_type_1)
        .limitToFirst(20);
```

then I get `lastMessageId`:

```
keyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    oldestPostId = child.getKey();
                 }
            }
         }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and I start `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter`:

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage,MessageViewHolder>(
            FriendlyMessage.class,
            R.layout.item_message,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            keyRef,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("messages").child(room)) {...}
```

in `isScrollCompleted()` method(in recyclerview.addOnScrollListener),I'm doing this:

```
 private void isScrollCompleted() {
   if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
       && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            keyRef=mFirebaseDatabaseReference
                    .child("messagesKeys")
                    .child(usernameFromEmail(mFirebaseUser.getEmail()))
                    .child(room_type_1)
                    .orderByKey()
                    .startAt(oldestPostId)
                    .limitToFirst(limit);



            mFirebaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            keyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    boolean is=true;
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        oldestPostId = child.getKey();

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
    }
```

So I want everytime after scroll is complete, make a new `keyRef`,refresh `firebaseIndexAdapter`,and show next 20 messages, but this is not working!
After I make the new `keyRef` and refresh using `mFirebaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, no new posts and the first twenty posts disappear.

My question is whether it is better in to load 20 by 20 items every time starting from `.startAt(oldestPostId)`,or load 20, then 40,then 60 messages?
Because if I start everytime from `oldestPostId`,how to back and show past twenty messages again?

Answer (score 0):

you obviously do not append the newly loaded items to the `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s items in a proper manner ...

```
String lastOneKey = null; int limit = 20;

keyRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(limit).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        /* that key needs to be updated in here */
        lastOneKey = childSnapshot.getKey();
    });
});
```

and then in the `isScrollCompleted()` method:

```
keyRef.orderByKey().startAt(lastKnownKey).limitToFirst(limit).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        /* and it needs to be updated in here */
        lastOneKey = childSnapshot.getKey();
    });
});
```

instead of blanking the adapter, one has to add an item and then notify the `RecyclerView.Adapter` about an item being inserted (the adapter-position, where a new item is being added, is always the length of the already existing items, hence that index is 0 based)... one could also insert a range of 20 at once - but better start simple. Would even suggest to add a getter/setter for the last one key to the `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

@see [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot).

Comment: thanks man,but i'm not so good in firebase,i dont now how to use function...but my problem is not how to get lastOneKey,its working correctly in my code,on start i get correctly lastOnekey,and every time when i scroll,i get correctly lastOnekey of next 20 items..my problem is,when scroll is completed,and i make new keyRef with .startAt(lastOnekey),and refresh adapter,nothing happens...if i try,instead of refresh, re activate adapter,then appears next twenty items,but previous 20 items disappears...not append new messages,but are replaced with new ones...I want to show a new message below...

Comment: whether it is even possible to do with firebaseindexrecycleradapter?